# Is there a recommended way to test Docker compose file (ideally, deployed as stacks)?

Tags: docker, testing, docker-compose, docker-swarm

In the philosphy that every piece of software should be tested, is there a way to test a Docker compose file?

We are already aware of the Docker recommended way to test individual containers' Dockerfiles, with a `sut` service:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/automated-testing/

Yet, it is common to then assemble several containers as `services` of a `docker-compose.yml` file. Yet, we are not aware of any "recommended" (by the official doc, nor the community) approach to implement such test.

---

Naïvely, we could write some `docker-compose.stacktest.yml` along the line of:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  stacktest:
    image: my-test-image
    command: test.sh
```

Then run it something like:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml -c docker-compose.stacktest.yml tester
```

Yet we are interested to see if there is something more generally accepted out there?

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches I would follow is to use testcontainers-java 
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java
It has a feature where it runs a docker-compose file 
https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/docker_compose/

The idea can be to write a bunch of tests in Java that runs the docker-compose and write assertions on them.

I never tried testcontainers-java for this purpose but I think it will work